# Search multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Not sure if this is correct but I have to ask ...

Let's say that one of my users resides in the US, and his `country_id` is 1. Can I get the `ship_cost` based on the user's `country_id`?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ship_cost] => 1
            [country_id] => 1
            [country_code] => US
            [country_name] => United States
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ship_cost] => 0
            [country_id] => 0
            [country_code] => 
            [country_name] => 
        )

)
```

The html where I need to also include the `SHIP PRICE`:

```
<?php if( in_array($user_country_id, $shipArr) && $itemData[0]['user_id'] != $user_id ) { ?>
    <ul class="list-group margin-top-3">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class="badge">SHIP PRICE</span>
            Ships to <?php echo $itemTools->getLocationName($user_country_id); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: And whats your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one it will help you

```
<?php 
        $user_country_id = 1;
            $array = array(array('ship_cost' => 1,'country_id' => 1,'country_code' => 'US','country_name' => 'United States'),
                array('ship_cost' => 0,'country_id' => 0,'country_code' => 'Uk','country_name' => 'United Kingdom'));
            foreach ($array as $value) {
                if ($user_country_id == $value['country_id']) {
                    var_dump($value);
                }
            }
```

Change this code for what you expect

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$key = array_search(1, array_column($array,"country_id"));
if($key !== false)
{
    print "ship_cost : ".$array[$key]['ship_cost'];
}else
{
    print "ship_cost : unknown or not exists";
}
```

**Sample Test**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
<?php

function test($id, $array)
{
    $key = array_search($id, array_column($array,"country_id"));
    if($key !== false)
    {
        print "ship_cost : ".$array[$key]['ship_cost']."\n";
    }else
    {
        print "ship_cost : unknown or not exists\n";
    }
}

$array = array (
  array (
    'ship_cost' => '1',
    'country_id' => '1',
    'country_code' => 'US',
    'country_name' => 'United States',
  ),
  array (
    'ship_cost' => '0',
    'country_id' => '0',
    'country_code' => '',
    'country_name' => false,
  )
);

// Test1
test(1, $array);

// Test2
test(2, $array);
?>
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
ship_cost : 1
ship_cost : unknown or not exists
```

Answer (score 0):

> See the new changes here

```
$arr = array
    (
        "0" => array
            (
                "ship_cost" => 1,
                "country_id" => 1,
                "country_code" => "US",
                "country_name" => "United States",
            ),

        "1" => array
            (
                "ship_cost" => 0,
                "country_id" => 0,
                "country_code" => "",
                "country_name" => "",
            )
    );
```

Now Processing Your Array

```
 $user_coutry_id = 1;
 $ship_cost ="";
 foreach ($arr as $key =>  $value) {
    if($arr[$key]["country_id"]==$user_coutry_id){
         $ship_cost = $arr[$key]["ship_cost"];
    }
 } 
 echo $ship_cost;
// return 1 as you expect.
```

Comment: It returns 0 for me. Wouldn't that return the ship cost from $test[1]['ship_cost'] ? I don't want that one. In the question example, the ship_cost is the $test[0] ...

Comment: it will return 0 bcoz the ship cost for country 1 is 0. but can you elaborate more what your trying to do.. aur what are your doubts

Comment: exactly ... so it should be returning 1, because the user's country it is 1

Comment: I was saying that assign. the array key same as the country id so when ever you want any detail related to users country you wont be having a problem in it. this way its more simpler and country id wont be same so there is no chance of duplicate data. then the key of array will be the country id. and you will get your desired results every time

Comment: Or if you want your array like this i am making the changes to the answer. please check it out